# Envio de email para gmail (Codeigniter), aparece como spammer

Tags: codeigniter, email, envio-de-email, gmail

Tenho um problema no envio de emails para o GMail através do CodeIgniter.
Todos os email que envio não aparecem as imagens e ficam com uma mensagem do GMail a dizer que pode ser um *spammer*.
Existe alguma maneira de ultrapassar isso?

Segue um print de como me aparece o email no gmail:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deveria aparecer algo deste género (a imagem seguinte é como aparece no serviço de `webmail`):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código usado**:

```
$this->load->model('template_model');
            $mensagem = $this->template_model->addUtilizador($assunto, $msg);

            $config = array(
                'protocol'  => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'ssl://*********',
                'smtp_user' => '*****@*****.com',
                'smtp_pass' => '********',
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'validate'  => TRUE,
                'charset'   => 'utf-8',
                'mailtype'  => 'html',
                'useragent' => 'Centro de Eventos',
                'wordwrap'  => true,
                'priority' => 1
            );

            $this->load->library('email', $config);

            $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
            $this->email->from('eventos@fe.up.pt', 'Centro de Eventos FEUP');
            $this->email->to($destinatarios);
            $this->email->subject($assunto);
            $this->email->message($mensagem);
            $this->email->send()
```

Comment: Poste o código !

Comment: Estou atualmente com esse mesmo problema. Não consegui achar nenhuma solução por enquanto. O que acontece é que um envio smtp com remetente diferente do servidor que encaminha é um comportamento característico de spam. Não sei se tem solução.